# Ampscript to render First name not working. MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

`Hi %%=IIF(Empty(first name),"their", first name)=%%,`
Hi Folks,
I have tried to render this small script using AMPscript but seems like it's not working.
I have added the code I tried above and the screenshot of the error which gets.
please someone help me with this.

[image]

Comment: try adding brackets around first name [first name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference attributes with spaces without additional syntax:

`%%=IIF(Empty([first name]),"there", [first name])=%%,`

Generally speaking I'd recommending not using raw personalization strings. You should wrap them in the [**AttributeValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) function:

```
%%[

set @firstName = AttributeValue("first name")

]%%

<!-- other HTML -->

Hi %%=IIF(Empty(@firstName),"there", @firstName)=%%,
```